# How can I make RStudio-Server use code-snippets stored in Vim directory

Tags: r, vim, rstudio, code-snippets

I have list of files with code snippet stored in here:

[image]

My question is, is there a way I can modify my **[RStudio-Server setting](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets?version=1.0.136&mode=server)**
so that it can source the code snippets directly from my Vim directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do soft-linking:

```
# Save original RStudio snippets as another name
mv .R/snippets/r.snippets .R/snippets/r.originalRstudio.snippets

# Link Vim Snippets to RStudio snippets directory
ln -s  ~/.vim/snippets/r.snippets .R/snippets/
```